# AWS Placement Groups - how might two instances sharing the same hardware pose a problem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been thoroughly reading the AWS docs on [Placement Groups - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html#placement-groups-cluster). In the **Partition** as well as the **Spread** group sections, the use cases described seem to focus on failures that occur from having instances share the same hardware, for example:

> Launching instances in a spread placement group reduces reduces the risk of simultaneous failures that might occur when instances share the same underlying hardware

1. I'm trying to wrap my head around how a failure in an application
   on Instance A would affect Instance B *because of their shared
   hardware*
2. On a similar note, if this side effect was possible,
   wouldn't other instances be affected as well? (that aren't mine).
3. What are some real-life situations that this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reversed the cause and effect.

The issue is **not** that a problem with the application on virtual machine A could cause a problem with the application on virtual machine B because the two VMs share hardware.

The issue is that if the shared hardware itself fails, then both A and B will potentially fail simultaneously because of the failed shared hardware -- which they both depend on.

Spread placement prevents two or more critical services from being -- coincidentally and unknown to you -- deployed on the same physical hardware, which is a situation that would increase the likelihood of simultaneous failures from a single hardware cause.

Hardware failures in EC2 are relatively rare, but hardware does occasionally fail or become degraded.